# Match all elements in document array with input array

Tags: mongodb

The db has documents as follows.

```
{
    id: 1,
    items: ["a", "b", "c"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    items: ["a", "b"]
},
{
    id: 3,
    items: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}
```

I need to get records that have all items should include in the input query.

If input `["a", "b", "c"]` #1 and #2, should come. Because all items includes in the input. But not #3, because input has not "d".

If i use `{query: {$in: ["a", "b", "c"]}}` = all records is coming.

If i use `{query: {$all: ["a", "b", "c"]}}` = #1, #2 records is coming.

What is the query for this?

Comment: The two queries are exactly the same, I doubt they give different results.

Comment: Sorry, I modified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $eq: [
               "$items",
               { $setIntersection: ["$items", ["a", "b", "c"]] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```